# How to print a list of objects from firebase in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the snapshot from the firebase and setting in the setState method and the in the render method i just want to print the list. In the first place because firebase is returning an object the map function was not working and i found something Array.from(this.state.testList) which seems to work but nothing is displayed. I am attaching the code and my firebase tree so you can see what I am trying to do.

25-10-2019:
firstPoint:
  newsDesc: "Chris is promoted to scrum master!"
  newsTitle: "Chris is promoted!!"
secondPoint:
  newsDesc: "Christodoulos needed a change in his life"
  newsTitle: "Christodoulos is leaving"

In the code above i am getting the snapshot of 'kabalaNews' which will return me and object with the data and this object will have many other objects with the points and the each point has a title and a description.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {DB_CONFIG} from './Config';

export class printFirebase extends Component {
 constructor() {
    super()
    this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
    this.database=this.app.database().ref().child('kabalaNews');


    this.state = {
        testList: []
    }
 }

componentDidMount(){
    this.database.on('value' , snap=> {

        this.setState({
            testList:snap.val()
        });
    });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.testList);

    return (
        <div>       
           <div>
               {Array.from(this.state.testList).map(news => 
               <p>{news.25-10-2019.newsDesc} {news.25-10-2019.newsTitle} 
               </p>)}
           </div>
        </div>
    )
 }
}

export default printFirebase
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes:

1. I'd actually state the entire snapshot into the state, instead of just the values. This ensures you can meet two needs that you're bound to have in the future:

   1. The items will show up in the order in which you queried them, instead of in alphabetical order of their keys.
   2. You have access to the ID of each item, which is useful once you want to start manipulating the items.
2. You're using an invalid syntax for accessing properties here: `news.25-10-2019.newsDesc`. A JavaScript identifier cannot contain a `-`, so you'll need to use `[]` notation to access the value: `news["25-10-2019"].newsDesc`.

So in total that becomes:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.database.on('value' , snap=> {

        this.setState({
            testList:snap
        });
    });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.testList);

    return (
        <div>       
           <div>
               {this.state.testList.forEach(news => 
               <p>{news.val["25-10-2019"].newsDesc} {news.val["25-10-2019"].newsTitle} 
               </p>)}
           </div>
        </div>
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help now its working as expected!